# How to set Multiplier of heightAnchor in SnapKit - swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, snapkit

I am a new iOS programming. And i really enjoy this library of setting constraint of my views. But now i am coming with a doubt which in `NSLayoutConstraint` we can adjust height with `multiplier` of our main view. But i don't know how to achieve this in SnapKit.

Here what `NSLayoutConstraint` provides

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        cardViewInstance.mainCardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: marginOffset),
        cardViewInstance.mainCardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        cardViewInstance.mainCardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        cardViewInstance.mainCardView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/5)
        ])
```

This what i have done with `SnapKit`

```
cardViewInstance.mainCardView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(view)
        make.topMargin.equalTo(marginOffset)

        make.leading.equalTo(self.view)
        make.leadingMargin.equalTo(20)

        make.trailing.equalTo(self.view)
        make.trailingMargin.equalTo(-20)


    }
```

Now i am stuck for setting height as `multiplier` of the main view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code in `NSLayoutConstraint` and code in `SnapKit` of setting constraint are not same when display.

You know when you set `cardViewInstance.mainCardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: marginOffset)` its view will be stayed on top and padding from top as you have set in `marginOffset`. and in SnapKit you set

`make.top.equalTo(view)
 make.topMargin.equalTo(marginOffset)`

So, this is wrong because you cannot set `top` and `topMargin` at the same time because it not like what you have set in `NSLayoutConstraint`

So please correct that with something like (according to document):

```
make.top.equalTo(view).offset(marginOffset)
```

For you question how to set `multiplier` you can achieve by declare a variable something like `view.frame.height / 2` and you can apply in you `SnapKit` constraint `make.height.equalTo(view.frame.height / 5)`

This is how the whole code look likes

```
cardViewInstance.mainCardView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(view).offset(marginOffset)


        make.leading.equalTo(self.view).offset(20)


        make.trailing.equalTo(self.view).offset(-20)

        make.height.equalTo(view.frame.height / 5)

    }
```

Hope that help :D

Comment: The ```make.height.equalTo(view.frame.height / 5)``` syntax should be improved to```make.height.equalTo(view).multipliedBy(0.2)```